# What UnitRange Type in Julia mean?

Tags: julia

I try to read [Julia code](https://github.com/SimonDanisch/SchroedingersSmoke.jl/blob/master/src/MatlabPort.jl#L38) having OOP strongly typed backgrownd. I get most of it, yet `UnitRange{Int};` and the way it is used are not clear for me: is it an array or just an an integer? Can any one present an analog of `UnitRange` type in some strongly typed language?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's just have a look. We can create a `UnitRange{Int}` explicitly by calling it's constructor

```
julia> UnitRange{Int}(3,5) # equivalent to just saying 3:5
3:5

julia> typeof(ans)
UnitRange{Int64}
```

Using the `@which` macro we can find out where the constructor and the type are defined:

```
julia> @which UnitRange{Int}(3,5)
(::Type{UnitRange{T}})(start, stop) where T<:Real in Base at range.jl:255
```

namely in `range.jl` line 255. There we find (`@edit` might be useful):

```
struct UnitRange{T<:Real} <: AbstractUnitRange{T}
    start::T
    stop::T
    UnitRange{T}(start, stop) where {T<:Real} = new(start, unitrange_last(start,stop))
end
```

Hence it really *is* two integers for `T = Int64`. Using the same technique we can find out that iterating and indexing of `UnitRange`s is defined in the same file from line 563 on. Therefore, a `UnitRange{Int}` is a type with two integer fields which defines an indexing and iterator interface. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/interfaces/index.html for more information on interfaces.

Comment: You can also do: `julia> fieldnames(UnitRange{Int64}) # (:start, :stop)`

Comment: Indeed. Another way is to click "source" in the documentation https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/base/collections/#Base.UnitRange

Comment: A little bit "safer" if you just want to watch the code, is to use `@less`, which will just open a pager, instead of opening the file with an editor. :)

Comment: @crstnbr: Loved [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/base/collections/#Base.UnitRange) link - could not google directly with "UnitRange Julia"...

Comment: Glad I could help.